# Computing $e^{ip\cdot x} \circ \nabla \circ e^{-ip\cdot x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, operator-theory

Let $e^{ip\cdot x}$ be the multiplication by $e^{ip\cdot x}$ operator. Then, according to a textbook I am reading (*Quantum Field Theory* by Folland),
$$e^{ip\cdot x} \circ \nabla \circ e^{-ip\cdot x} = \nabla - p.$$
However when I compute this on some test function $f$ I obtain:
$$(e^{ip\cdot x} \circ \nabla \circ e^{-ip\cdot x})f = e^{ip\cdot x}\nabla(e^{-ip\cdot x}f) = e^{ip\cdot x}\big[-ipe^{-ip\cdot x}f + e^{-ip\cdot x}\nabla f\big] = -ipf + \nabla f.$$
Hence according to my calculation above,
$$e^{ip\cdot x} \circ \nabla \circ e^{-ip\cdot x} = \nabla - ip.$$

Have I made a mistake?

Comment: Comment proposed by metaUser: What is $p$ ? I would assume $p$ is the momentum, a $4$ dimensional vector, what is then $\nabla$ ? does it act only on spatial coordinates? Have you differentiated the dot product correctly?

Comment: @J.G. $p$ is the momentum portion of the 4-momentum and $\nabla$ is taken with respect to the spatial coordinates $x$.

Comment: What you have looks right since the conjugation is not self-adjoint ($\nabla$ is not self-adjoint, $-i\nabla$ is). It could be just a typo.

Comment: Actually, I would dare to say that it is a typo since $-i\nabla$ is the momentum operator so $i\nabla - p$ makes sense and $\nabla-p$ doesn't as much.